# phpunit only throwing fatal errors if test is specified with filter

Tags: php, phpunit

`phpunit .`

results in failed tests

`phpunit MyFileTest.php`

results in failed tests

`phpunit --filter testSomething MyFileTest.php`

results in a fatal error that should have been caught with the prior methods of running the test.

phpunit: 3.7.7

php: 5.3.10

any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, or even the error message, it's really hard to help you.

You probably have some dependencies that are loaded in previous tests, and that are not there when running the single test.